# Simple python regex not working as intended

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract out the number before the `-` and the rest of the string after it, but it's not able to extract out both. Here's the output from the interactive terminal:

```py
>>> a = '#232 - Hello There'
>>> re.findall('#(.*?) - (.*?)', a)
[('232', '')]
```

Why is my regex not working properly?

Comment: Do you even *need* a regex for that? `split` and `strip` will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.*?` is *non-greedy* i.e. it will match the smallest substring, you need the *greedy* version i.e. `.*` (matches longest substring) for the latter one:

```
In [1143]: a = '#232 - Hello There'                                                                                                                                                                         

In [1144]: re.findall('#(.*?) - (.*?)', a)                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[1144]: [('232', '')]

In [1145]: re.findall('#(.*?) - (.*)', a)                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[1145]: [('232', 'Hello There')]
```

---

But you should use `str` methods to process such simple cases e.g. using **`str.split`** with splitting on `-`:

```
In [1146]: a.split(' - ')                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[1146]: ['#232', 'Hello There']
```

With **`str.partition`** on `-` and slicing:

```
In [1147]: a.partition(' - ')[::2]                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[1147]: ('#232', 'Hello There')
```

Answer (score 0):

This expression might likely extract those desired values:

```
([0-9]+)\s*-\s*(.*)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpzWDo/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

print(re.findall("([0-9]+)\s*-\s*(.*)", "#232 - Hello There"))
```

#### Output

```
[('232', 'Hello There')]
```

Comment: "might likely" ? regexes are very deterministic

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine, you're just using the wrong function from `re`. The following matches things correctly:

```
m = re.fullmatch('#(.*?) - (.*?)', a)
```